# Installing a ruby gem - --remote

Tags: ruby, rubygems

If I want to install a ruby gem, and wrote after the command `--remote`, what does that mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation will be restricted to the ’’remote’’ domain. For example, an —install operation will go directly to the remote servers.

[Description of common parameters](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/13#page49)